# Issue with personalized buttons in Marketing Cloud email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, hyperlink

I need to send an email with a personalized button to link each customer to a satisfaction survey hosted by QuestionPro (www.questionpro.com)

In the email I tried different buttons or hyperlinks and only the last one - 4 - is giving the right link for the right customer but is not the most user friendly.
See below the different HTML versions:

1 - If a simple hyperlink is defined:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <u>
    <span style="font-size:16px;"><b style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;; font-size: medium;">
      <b style="font-size: 16px;">
        <span style="font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot;, helvetica, sans-serif;"><a alias="" conversion="true" data-linkto="https://" href="https://%%Survey URL%%" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255); text-decoration-line: none;" title="">Je r&eacute;ponds !</a></span> 
      </b> 
      </b></span> 
  </u>
</div>
```

The Hyperlink in the email sent becomes:

[click.contact.touring.be/?qs=b1d5559d3ed107c0c24e5e42142a5b2526241f3a1ef86418cd83b31f7aae9d1ddd0e10c6756b03322956665bd9e3140232295486c1020795](http://click.contact.touring.be/?qs=b1d5559d3ed107c0c24e5e42142a5b2526241f3a1ef86418cd83b31f7aae9d1ddd0e10c6756b03322956665bd9e3140232295486c1020795)

2 - If a Content Builder button is defined:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td class="innertd buttonblock" align="center" bgcolor="#007FFF" style=" border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; background-color: #007FFF;">
            <a target="_blank" style=" text-decoration: none; display: block; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #FFFF00; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border-color: #5D5D5D; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;" class="buttonstyles" href="https://%%Survey URL%%" title="Mon avis !" alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://">Je r&eacute;ponds !</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The Hyperlink in the email sent becomes:

[click.contact.touring.be/?qs=b1d5559d3ed107c0ff7177660edf6efd3a57919a25d44e7d9aaa80faa125623c2e55efddf2340d202c90746c8365321d89c0806900a65c80](http://click.contact.touring.be/?qs=b1d5559d3ed107c0ff7177660edf6efd3a57919a25d44e7d9aaa80faa125623c2e55efddf2340d202c90746c8365321d89c0806900a65c80)

3 - If an HTML button is like:

```
<table align="center" style="border-radius:4px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#fbec15">
  <tr>
    <td class="mobile-hide">
      <img src="http://image.contact.touring.be/lib/fe8e137275630d7d7d/m/1/button-left.jpg" alt="" style="display:block;" height="35" border="0" width="3">
    </td>
    <td style="font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:18px; color:#00418c; font-weight:bold; padding:0 20px;" align="center">
      <a href="https://%%Survey URL%%" style="color:#00418c; text-decoration:none;">Oui, je réponds !
      </a>
    </td>
    <td class="mobile-hide">
      <img src="http://image.contact.touring.be/lib/fe8e137275630d7d7d/m/1/button-right.jpg" alt="" style="display:block;" height="35" border="0" width="3">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then the Hyperlink in the email sent becomes:

[click.contact.touring.be/?qs=b1d5559d3ed107c0ff7177660edf6efd3a57919a25d44e7d9aaa80faa125623c2e55efddf2340d202c90746c8365321d89c0806900a65c80](http://click.contact.touring.be/?qs=b1d5559d3ed107c0ff7177660edf6efd3a57919a25d44e7d9aaa80faa125623c2e55efddf2340d202c90746c8365321d89c0806900a65c80)

4 - If a simple text is written like:

```
https://%%Survey URL%%
```

then in the email sent the hyperlink is:

https://www.questionpro.com/a/TakeSurvey?id=5651649&rd=333699823

and the survey is correctly accessible

Comment: The first three are masked with click tracking, which puts a unique URL that will redirect to the URL you placed there.  Is the issue just how the link appears or is it the actual functionality of the link.  If click tracking is breaking your URL, this is likely an issue to push to SFMC support.

Comment: in hyperlink use `redirectto()` function with the personalised string.

Comment: Thanks already for your answers. I'll contact the SFMC support.

Comment: To Abhishek can you explain how I've to write the redirectto() function in HTML. I'm far to be an HTML expert...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this was posted a month ago, but if you're still wondering what the code should look like in MC:

```
<a href="%%=redirectto([Survey URL])=%%"> Link text </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Marketing Cloud Content Builder, option 4 worked for the varying URLs. When setting up the personalization, this will need to be a bit forced applying "https://%%Survey URL%%" to the content on the HTML side and not in the WYSIWYG. This didn't work for the application to a button feature itself, however, you can create a button with a plain text box and apply a border and your standard styling for the button.